# AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get occurs stackoverflow exception

Tags: android

I used `list.sublist()` on android,but occured a stackoverflow exception,here is the code.

```
itemList = itemList.subList(0, index);
adapter.setData(itemList);
```

It is weird after check the source of `SubList`.

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is. Add some more code.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `subList`:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

which means that you should not store the returned list to the list that you supplied.

Try following code:

```
List<Type> tempList = itemList.subList(0, index);
itemList = new ArrayList<>(); // don't use clear()
itemList.addAll(tempList);
adapter.setData(itemList);
```